# Laravel 7 - Eloquent ORM get data from 2 tables when using one to one relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello fellow programmers.

I know how to get Laravel Eloquent ORM data from relationships: one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many.
Not a big deal here. The issue is something that I don't know if is possible or, perhaps escaped me in my study.

Example on a relation one-to-many:

table 'Users'

- id
- name

table 'Phones'

- id
- id_user
- phone_number

How can I get all fields from both tables when I run

```
$results = \App\Models\Users::find(1)->phones;
```

When I run this, $results will only give me records from the Phones table!

I know how to get that information using raw sql queries or Query Builder, but is it possible to get them with Eloquent Relationships?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend accessing relationship attributes via a relationship objects. You want to add all attributes to a phone object, but that's not a very good practice in this scenario.

You might try this:

```php
$user = User::first();

$phones = $user->phones()->with('user')->get();

// Then you are able to access user attributes from a phone object like this:
foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    print($phone->user->name);
}
```

A more advanced, but also faster and more proper solution is to follow [this article](https://reinink.ca/articles/optimizing-circular-relationships-in-laravel):

```php
$user = User::first();

$user->phones->each->setRelation('user', $user);

// Then you are able to access user attributes from a phone object like this:
foreach ($user->phones as $phone) {
    print($phone->user->name);
}
```

Comment: Tanks for your response. In a way, it answers my question, but I still don't see the benefits of using a solution like that versus a single SQL query like this:

`SELECT users.name, phones.phone_number FROM users, phones WHERE users.id = phones.id_user`

This query gives me:

`user1, 111111 | user1, 222222 | user4, 900003 | user4, 989898`
Can you explain the benefits, IN THIS CASE, of using Eloquent and not a regular SQL Raw Query?

Answer (score 1):

In User model add following function:

```php
public function phones(){
return $this->hasMany(Phone::class);
}
```

Then you can fetch Users with phones :

```php
$user = User::find($id);
$phones = $user->phones()->get();
```

or:

```php
User::with('phones')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
$results = \App\Models\Users::find(1)->phones;
```

you can also include the phones like this

```
$results = \App\Models\Users::with('phones')->find(1);
```

All the phones of the user will be accessible through `$results->phones`.

Answer (score 0):

Fellow programmers, thank you for your appreciated responses.
Testing your solutions have made me figuring out how to achieve the goal.

In resume:

```
    $res = User::with('phones')->first();

    echo $res->name'<br>'; 
    foreach($res->phones()->get() as $phone){
        echo $phone->phone_number.'<br>';
    }
```

This did the job.
Thank you @Kevin Bui, @Mohammad Aliyari and @Douwe de Haan for you help.